# Deploying file with jenkins to Artifactory as Maven artefact without using maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I'm using Jenkins version 1.532.1 and Artifactory version 3.1.0.

When you configure a job in jenkins ci, at the category "Build Environment" you can select "Generic-Artifactory Integration" and enter the path to a file you want to deploy to the Artifactory.

But I want to have the file deployed as a Maven artifact with maven metadata and dependencies defiend in a pom.xml.
Is this possible with selecting the "Maven3-Artifactory Integration", defining Include Patterns and Deployment properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, for Maven artifacts you should use the "Maven3-Artifactory Integration" and not the "Generic-Artifactory Integration", as described [in the documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ConfiguringMaven2andMaven3Builds).

Please note that although it's possible to use with generic build, we strongly suggest using Maven3 build for that.